# Sumar valores de una tabla y guardar resultado en otra tabla

Tags: php

hola me pueden ayudar con esto 
1.tengo una BD llamada peluquería y consta de 4 tablas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la tabla llamada barbero tengo una columna llamada total_cortes y el cual su valor se encuentra en cero lo que quiero hacer es que de la tabla comprobante  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se sumen el valor de los cortes que realiza cada barbero y ese resultado se registre en la tabla barbero en la columna total de corte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida te sugiero editar y mostrar lo que llevas al momento

Comment: Basicamente debes hacer una consulta en ambas tablas y almacenar los resultados en diferentes variables, luego esas variables las utilizas para hacer el insert en la tabla que deseas.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL (con las capturas de pantalla no podemos hacer pruebas) con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si estas respuestas han aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

tienes que realizar una consulta con SQL que agrupe por el campo `bar_id` y que use la función `sum` en `valor_de_corte`.

Te recomiendo que te hagas el curso de sql de w3school es muy sencillo e interesante.

Comment: hola muchas gracias pero de esa manera solo se ejecuta una consulta y no se guarda el valor en la columna total_cortes

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo la siguiente consulta de actualización de datos:

```
UPDATE barbero JOIN (
    SELECT bar_id,COUNT(*) cortes
      FROM corte GROUP BY 1 
  ) c1 USING(bar_id)
  SET total_cortes=cortes;
```

La idea es calcular el número de cortes de cada barbero y después combinar esos resultados a través de su `bar_id` para hacer una actualización de datos.

Parece complicada porque es un `UPDATE` con un `JOIN` a un subconsulta con un `GRUOP BY` pero, en cuanto te acostumbres a hacerlas, te saldrán solas. Es cuestión de práctica.

Adjunto dataset simplificado para comprobar la solución, es preferible a las capturas de pantalla:

```
CREATE TABLE barbero(
  bar_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  bar_nombre varchar(31),
  total_cortes int
  );
CREATE TABLE corte(
  id_comprobante int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  bar_id int,
  valor_de_corte float,
  FOREIGN KEY(bar_id) REFERENCES barbero(bar_id)
  );
INSERT INTO barbero (bar_nombre) VALUES
  ('MANUEL'),('JOSE'),('SCARLETH'),('CAROLINA');
INSERT INTO corte (bar_id, valor_de_corte) VALUES
  (4,3),
  (3,3),
  (2,3),
  (1,3),
  (1,3),
  (2,3),
  (3,3),
  (4,3),
  (4,3),
  (2,3),
  (4,5),
  (3,5);
```

El resultado obtenido, para un `SELECT * FROM barbero;` tras el `UPDATE`, será:

```
1   MANUEL  2
2   JOSE    3
3   SCARLETH    3
4   CAROLINA    4
```